# URL Rewriting domain to use subdirectory as root; still shows that directory in URL in Analytics?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, google-analytics

I set up a certain domain to rewrite into a folder, shown below, but have been having people show up in that folder in Google Analytics.

in short: /c/ -> root when from domain, but GA still shows domain/c/ in Visitors Flow

root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?certain-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !c/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.txt -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.txt    
Options -Indexes
```

and /c/'s .htaccess is just an edited [html5boilerplate one](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) with the only difference being the same php and txt rewrite above.

But on Google Analytics, more than half of my visitors are still ending up on /c/index.php.

Visitor Flow: http://i.imgur.com/JwtcTFI.png

I haven't seen /c/ in my URL, so I really don't have a clue what's going on.

Any ideas? I do use relative URLs (is this a bad idea?) so that causes the flow to continue in the /c/ folder.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oo, I found the answer! It seems like **www.domain was redirecting to domain/c/index.php**. I had a rewrite rule to remove the "www" in the /c/.htaccess, but not the root .htaccess.

I fixed it by **adding code to remove the "www" in the root htaccess too BEFORE the domain>>directory rewrite.** (after didn't seem to work)

I added

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

above

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?certain-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !c/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [L]
```

(in the root htaccess)

edit: It also probably has to do with the (www.), I dropped that due to redundancy. Now it's just `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^certain-domain.com$ [NC]`

I also added a rewrite for /c/ to root in the /c/ .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /c/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rules do nothing to prevent people from directly accessing `/c/whatever`. If you want to prevent that, you need to add an extra rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /c/
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried that in both the root and directory htaccess and domain/c/ still works. Weirdly enough, it works for domain/c/c/ redirecting to domain root.
I'm also trying to figure out why they land on /c/index.php in the first place. I dunno if it even appears in their URLs.